# How to save urca results as a data frame in R

Tags: r

I have run 2 unit root tests using the `urca` package. I am trying to figure out how to save the summary results in a combined data frame.

```
library(stats)
library(urca)

adf_test <- ur.df(ldeaths,type = 'drift',selectlags = 'AIC')
pp_test <- ur.pp(ldeaths,type = 'Z-tau')

summary(adf_test)
summary(pp_test)
```

TIA!

Comment: Did you try  `ADF <- summary(adf_test)` ? and `PP <- summary(pp_test)` ?

Comment: It's not clear how these two objects with various substructures of different lengths could be meaningfully represented as a data frame, but you can at least get tables of the coefficients with `summary(adf_test)@testreg$coefficients`

Comment: thanks @AllanCameron, works perfectly!